# UICollectionView headerReferenceSize set in delegate not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewdelegate

I'm trying to use the `headerReferenceSize` in my custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.

I have set the `collectionView:layout:referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:` method in the collectionView delegate:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, height: round(250*(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width/414)))
}
```

This gets called once when the view loads. However, the custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout keeps retrieving the size set in the storyboard, and not from my delegate. Why is this?

Comment: You should show the code for `collectionView:layout:referenceSizeForHeaderInSection`. You know it get's called because you set a breakpoint or log?

Comment: @beyowulf added, I printed a log